# Order topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is discret topology?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

> Let $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dotso\}$ and $(\mathbb{N},<)$ with the usual ordering $<$. Let $\tau_<$ be the order topology with regards to $<$. Then $\tau_<$ is the discrete topology (topology of all subsets) on $\mathbb{N}$.

I am asked to proof this, but I doubt that this is correct...

A base of the order topology is given by: $\mathcal{O}=\{(u,v)|u,v\in X, u<v\}\cup\{(-\infty, u), (u,\infty)|u\in X\}\cup\{X\}$

That means for $V\in\tau_<$ there is for every $v\in V$ a $U\in\mathcal{O}$ such that $v\in U\subseteq V$.

We want to show, that $\tau_<=\tau_{disc}$, so every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is open.
Clearly it sufficies to show, that $\{n\}$ is open for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $n\neq 0$ this is obviously true, since $\{n\}=(n-1,n+1)$.

But I do not see, why $\{0\}$ should be an open set, with regards to $\tau_<$.
The only elements of $\mathcal{O}$ which contain $0$ are the sets $(-\infty, n)$ with $n>0$.
But with these we do not get equality.

So there is no chance to get $\{0\}=\bigcup \mathcal{U}$ where $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{O}$. So $\{0\}$ should not be open. In fact no subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which has $0$ as an element should be open. So $\tau_<\neq\tau_{disc}$

Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(-\infty,n)\not\subset \mathbb N$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I know. That is the problem.... So am I right and the statement is false, or is $\{0\}$ somehow open?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner For the usual order on $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, why isn't it true that $\ (-\infty, n) = \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\ $?  I suspect I'm misunderstanding something here, since the identity $\ (-\infty, 1) = \{0\}\ $ would seem to me to be a simple way to get $\ \{0\}\ $ to be open.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera In fact this should be correct. I checked my notes and we defined $(-\infty, u)=\{v\in X|v<u\}$. So for $X=\mathbb{N}$ it is in fact $(-\infty, 1)=\{0\}$... So I understand the comment of J.W. Tanner now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the notation of your open rays as $(n,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,n)$. I personally find the following notation less confusing:

Define ${x\!\!\uparrow}=\{y\in X\mid y>x\}$ and ${x\!\!\downarrow}=\{y\in X\mid y<x\}$, then the set $\mathcal B=\{{x\!\!\uparrow}\mid x\in X\}\cup\{{x\!\!\downarrow}\mid x\in X\}$ forms a subbase for the order topology. You could get an open interval $(a,b)$ by taking the intersection of ${a\!\!\uparrow}\cap {b\!\!\downarrow}$.

Now for $X=\mathbb N$ it should become clear that $\{0\}={1\!\!\downarrow}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime I checked the definition of $(-\infty, u)$ which is in this case $\{n\in\mathbb{N}| n<u\}$, which makes everything nice and simple... Since $(-\infty, 1)=\{0\}$ by that definition.

Comment: @Cornman Exactly, it's just a notational difference, the idea does not change. In general, when working *inside* a space $X$, you can remember that all the sets involved are interpreted as subsets of $X$ (since other sets make no sense *inside* the context of $X$)

Comment: You are right. Should have paid more attention here. I was to much focused on the 'usual' interpretation of $-\infty$, which lead to my misunderstanding.